# jquery appoints the wrong height of an element with property border-size: border-box

Tags: jquery, css, border-box, box-sizing

I have an element with an arbitrary height.
Element have properties box-sizing: border-box.
If using jquery appoint 100px height, the result would be the height of the element is equal to 120.
What could be wrong?

js:

```
$('#element').height(100);
```

css:

```
#element{
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yurri_87/8sLovkba/

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if it solved your confusion to close this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height()` function only sets height of element, if you want to set total height **including padding, border and margin** as 100 then use `outerHeight()`

```
$('#element').outerHeight(100);
```

By using `height()` you are forcing jQuery to set height of element itself as 100 and thats why even if you use `box-sizing: border-box` , it wont make any difference.

For further reference:
http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

*I hope it helps*